# Swift tutorial foodtracker: tap gesture method not called

Tags: ios, swift

I am playing around with the apple swift tutorial for the Foodtracker and try to open now the Photo library with the tap gesture.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  FoodTracker
//
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    // MARK: Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mealPhotoView: UIImageView!

    // MARK: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        // Dismiss the picker if the user canceled.
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        // The info dictionary contains multiple representations of the image, and this uses the original.
        let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

        // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.
        mealPhotoView.image = selectedImage

        // Dismiss the picker.
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK: Actions

    @IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("selectImage called!")
        // Hide the keyboard.
        nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()

        // UIImagePickerController is a view controller that lets a user pick media from their photo library.
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

        // Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

        // Make sure ViewController is notified when the user picks an image.
        imagePickerController.delegate = self

        presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func setDefaultLabelText(sender: AnyObject) {
        nameLabel.text = "Default Meal name"

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Handle the user input on textfield through delegate callback (self == this)
        nameTextField.delegate = self
    }

    // MARK: UITextFieldDelegate
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // Hide the keyboard.
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        nameLabel.text = textField.text
    }

}
```

anyhow when the simulator starts up and I tap on the photo the library view is not shown. I even cannot see me debugging message.

I already did remove the outlets and actions and did the whole process again by adding the UIImageView Outlet, add the gesture recognizer, add the action of the gesturerecognizer but still not happening what it should.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the problem - I did not enable the User Interaction which is set to false by default.

Comment: I also had to disable the 'Cancel touches in View' attribute of the 'Tap Gesture Recogniser' only the click event on the image was recognised.